# PowerShell VMWare Connect-VIServer

Tags: powershell, virtual-machine, vmware, vsphere, import-module

I can't run Connect-VIServer. I'm getting "Connect-VIServer : Method not found." I have imported all of the VMware modules. Thoughts?

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of PowerCLI installed? If so, uninstall the older version.

Answer (score 1):

run `get-Module -Name VMware* -ListAvailable`

most common cause is that you have more than one version installed.  I would use that command to gather the info and then remove any of the older ones that might be on your pc